# How to get value from database in Hindi and Punjabi font and display in hindi and punjabi

Tags: php, jquery, utf-8, meta

Actually i want to know how to show the `Hindi` or `Punjabi` font in my page. Actually i did insert in database successfully but while showing, it results me like this `à¤•à¥à¤¯à¤¾ à¤¬à¤¾à¤¤`. This is my php Code for getting values from database

```
$result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");//the main trick
    $cmd = "select * from user";
    $result = mysql_query($cmd);    
   // $selectQuery=mysql_query("Select * from user");
while($fetchRow=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```